# How can I not to return a field from object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

E.g., I've got the following object:

```
a = {
  "data": {
    "foo": {
      "name": "Alex"
    }
  },
  "randomField": {}
}
```

My goal is to return the following object (e.g., delete *randomField* or return a.data but save the key).

```
{
  "data": {
    "foo": {
      "name": "Alex"
    }
  }
}
```

I was thinking about the following solution:

```
return {
  data: a.data
}
```

And it looks like I can just use `return { a.data };` instead.

Comment: There are any number of ways it could be done. This... seems like the most immediate, obvious solution--so what are you really asking?

Comment: So after you thought about it what problems did you encounter doing it?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm wondering whether it's the most popular way to do it.

Comment: What's the most popular way is totally based on opinion... You must check what is your needs and goals, as said by Dave in the first comment, the most obvious solution is `a.data`, it's simple and fast, but you must check if this really helps you, for example, if every `a` object will have `data` property and etc...

Comment: `return { a.data };` is a syntax error for me.

Comment: The reason you are getting downvotes is there was never really a problem here...or a real question

Comment: @A.Karnaval No, you can't just `return { a.data }`, that's not valid object syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the context of your code. If you just want to delete a key-value pair from your object then `delete a.randomField` will do the trick. You could return `a` afterwards, but note that this modifies `a` if it was passed into your function from the outside. In other words:

```
function foo(x) {
    delete x.randomField;
    return x;
}
```

would lead to the following behavior:

```
a = {
  "data": {
    "foo": {
      "name": "Alex"
    }
  },
  "randomField": {}
}
foo(a)
console.log(a.randomValue) // gives "undefined"
```

Such side effects are usually considered a dangerous practice.

Another option is to create a new object and copy all attributes except for the one you want to remove. That approach leaves you with two different ways to copy your object: Deep and shallow copies. What you are doing with `{data: a.data}` is effectively a shallow copy of a part of your object: While the outer object is new, the inner object `a.data` is still the same. Consider the following code:

```
function foo(x) {
    return {data: x.data}
}
b = foo(a)
a.foo.name = "Bob";
console.log(b.foo.name) // Gives "Bob"
```

Your way of creating a partial shallow copy is okayish, if you want to transfer a single attribute, but becomes tedious if you want to copy one hundred fields with one exception. In that case, you could do something like this:

```
function foo(x) {
    y = {}
    Object.keys(x).forEach(function(key) {
        if (key !== "randomField") {
            y[key] = x[key]
        }
    });
    return y;
}
```

Which works in every modern Browser since IE9. Note that this still exhibits the properties of shallow copies, i.e. `b = foo(a)` followed by a modification of `a.data` would still lead to changes in `b.data` as well

Then there are deep copies. Implementing these correctly is a little bit more complicated. Common approaches include serializing the object into JSON and then deserializing again (which leads to an entirely new object, thats fully detached from the original object that was serialized). After doing this you can `delete copiedObject.randomField`, as that will no longer affect your original object. However, the serialization step can lead to loss of values, if they are not serializable. Because of this, I would strongly suggest that you look at lodashs `_.omit` method ([docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#omit)) if a partial deep copy is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use ES6 you can use destructuring to remove a field.

```
const a = {
  "data": {
    "foo": {
      "name": "Alex"
    }
  },
  "randomField": {}
};

const { randomField, ...rest } = a;
return rest;
```

Answer (score 0):

If foo is the object you described above

Possibility 1

```js
return { data: foo.data };
```

Possibility 2

```js
delete foo.randomField;
return foo;
```

Just be aware that if you pass foo to a function it is passed as a reference, so every change done to the passed object is directly done to the original object.